# Kindly explain the meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't understand the meaning of the second part of this sentence, particularly terms "outbreaks" and "recalls".

"For now, the focus at Clear Labs is on indexing for the enterprise, one that includes creating a future where food brands can be proactive rather than reactive to outbreaks or recalls."

I suppose "outbreaks" means a disease outbreak, but have no idea about "recall".

Here's a link to [the original article](http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/15/clear-labs-aims-to-be-google-search-for-gmos-in-our-packaged-food/#.n1eslf:PcCS).

Comment: A "recall" (a noun) does not share a definition with recall (a verb or a noun which can mean remembering--"I recall having heard that before"--or the ability to remember--"John has excellent powers of recall."  A recall (again, a noun) is the attempt of, say, a drug company to issue a warning about a tainted drug supply and ask retailers and consumers to return the drug to its makers. A recall in this sense means an instance of "asking for something to be returned."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct about the meaning of "outbreak", but I'd say it's referring to *allergy* outbreaks in the given context:

> How much gluten, genetically modified organisms and **other allergens**
>   are in that cereal you ate this morning?

Regarding "recall":

> recall: if a company recalls one of its products, it asks people who
>   have bought it to return it because there may be **something wrong** with
>   it

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/recall_1))

Put together, it means the new system should enable companies to *prevent* allergy or disease outbreaks or product recalls ("proactive"), as opposed to trying to deal with *actual* outbreaks or having to remove products from the market ("reactive").

> proactive: making things happen or change **rather than reacting to events**

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/proactive))